# jQuery: Find nearest checkbox with data id

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a form where user can add fields using dynamically. Now upon adding a checkbox user following html is embedded

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
       <label>Checkbox Label: </label>
       <input type="text" data-id="572004035" class="form-control checkbox_label" name="checkbox_name">      
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-md-3">
         <label>CheckBox Value</label>
         <input type="text" data-id="572004035" class="form-control checkbox_value " name="checkbox_value">
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-md-3">
         <label class="ceheckbox_text"></label><input type="checkbox" name="[]" data-id="572004035" class="checkbox_item">
    </div>
</div>
```

User can assign checkbox label and its value which is assigned to checkbox. I have assigned same  data-id to checkbox label, value and checkbox itself so that i can find the checkbox on change event.

But i am  not able to find the checkbox based on data-id attribute , Can someone please help to solve this. Below is my JS Code

```
 $form_holder.on('input','.checkbox_label', e => {
            let $target = $(e.target);
            let $id= $target.data('id'); 
            let $checkbox=$target.closest('.row').find('.checkbox_item').attr('data-id',$id);//this is not working 
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you're using the setter of `attr()` in an attempt to select the element. You instead need to use the attribute selector to find the `:checkbox` with the relevant `data-id`. Try this:

```js
let $form_holder = $('#form_holder');
$form_holder.on('input', '.checkbox_label', e => {
  let $target = $(e.target);
  let id = $target.data('id');
  let $checkbox = $target.closest('.row').find(`:checkbox[data-id="${id}"]`);
  console.log('Checkboxes found: ', $checkbox.length);  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="form_holder">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <label>Checkbox Label: </label>
      <input type="text" data-id="572004035" class="form-control checkbox_label" name="checkbox_name">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <label>CheckBox Value</label>
      <input type="text" data-id="572004035" class="form-control checkbox_value" name="checkbox_value">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <label class="ceheckbox_text"></label><input type="checkbox" name="[]" data-id="572004035" class="checkbox_item">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help Rory It solved my problem  ,  Pretty basic mistake i was making but really was unable to sort it out . Thanks again

Comment: @stackoverflowaccount To add on this answer, all of your variables are actually constants since their value never change, so you should declare them with the const keyword instead of the let keyword.